# Grpc access violation on client

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019, grpc, access-violation

I'm in the process of messing around with `GRPC`. Currently I'm using a `C#` web application as my `GRPC` server and I'm using a `C++` console application as the client.

I was able to successfully connect and communicate with the server with no issue. The problem arises when
I exit the `C++` console client application. Upon exiting an `Access Violation` is thrown.

**Stack trace**

```
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!`anonymous namespace'::ThreadInternalsWindows::thread_body  
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!__acrt_lock
ntdll.dll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection()
ntdll.dll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended()
ntdll.dll!RtlEnterCriticalSection()
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!__acrt_lock(__acrt_lock_id _Lock) Line 55
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!_free_dbg(void * block, int block_use) Line 1019
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!free(void * block) Line 32
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!gpr_free(void * p) Line 53
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!`anonymous namespace'::ThreadInternalsWindows::destroy_thread() Line 142
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!`anonymous namespace'::ThreadInternalsWindows::Join() Line 112
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!grpc_core::Thread::Join() Line 147
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!gc_completed_threads() Line 74
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!stop_threads() Line 331
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!grpc_timer_manager_set_threading(bool threaded) Line 351
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!grpc_shutdown_internal_locked() Line 175
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!grpc_shutdown_internal(void * __formal) Line 208
MeterReaderClientCpp.exe!`anonymous namespace'::ThreadInternalsWindows::thread_body(void * v) Line 128
```

**GRPC Client**

```
int main( )
{
    using namespace MeterReaderWeb::Services;
    using namespace google::protobuf::util;
    using namespace google::protobuf;


    std::cout << "Press enter\n";
    std::cin.ignore( );

    std::cout << "Calling Grpc service\n";

    std::fstream file{ R"(C:\Certificates\certificate.cer)", std::ios::in | std::ios::beg };
    if ( !file.is_open( ) )
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf( );

    grpc::SslCredentialsOptions options;
    options.pem_root_certs = buffer.str( );

    auto credentials{ grpc::SslCredentials( options ) };
    auto channel{ grpc::CreateChannel( "localhost:5001", credentials ) };
    auto stub{ MeterReadingService::NewStub( channel ) };

    ReadingPacket packet;
    packet.set_status( ReadingStatus::METER_READER_SUCCESS );
    packet.set_notes( "Here are some random notes" );

    auto message{ packet.add_readings( ) };    
    message->set_customer_id( 1 );
    message->set_reading_value( 10001 );

    auto timestamp{ message->mutable_reading_time( ) };
    timestamp->CopyFrom( TimeUtil::GetCurrentTime( ) );

    grpc::ClientContext context;
    StatusMessage response;
    if ( auto status{ stub->AddReading( &context, packet, &response ) }; status.ok( ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Added reading successfully\n";
        auto responseStatus{ response.status( ) };
        if ( responseStatus == ReadingStatus::METER_READER_SUCCESS )
        {
            std::cout << "Server status: success\n" 
                      << "Message: " << response.message( ) << '\n';

        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << status.error_message( ) << '\n';
        std::cerr << "Error Details: " << status.error_details( ) << '\n';
    }

    std::cin.ignore( );
}
```

I heavily used the `GRPC` `route_guide_client.cc` as a guide to help me write the above application.

I've tried adding calls to both `grpc_init( )` and `grpc_shutdown( )` even though their client examples don't contain either calls. But adding those had no effect.

What (if anything) am I missing here? Did I forget to call/populate something that the framework is attempting to clean up upon application exit?

Answer (score 1):

OK I believe I've found what was causing the issue.

In my original post I said:

> I've tried adding calls to both `grpc_init( )` and `grpc_shutdown( )` even though 
>   the client examples don't contain either calls. But
>   adding those had no effect."

This was true, but after re-reading the documentation for `grpc_shutdown( )` i noticed this (emphasis mine):

> The last call to `grpc_shutdown` will initiate cleaning up of grpc
>   library internals, which can happen in another thread. Once the
>   clean-up is done, no memory is used by grpc, nor are any instructions
>   executing within the grpc library. **Prior to calling, all application
>   owned grpc objects must have been destroyed.**

This is where I think I went wrong. I was calling `grpc_shutdown()` while I still had grpc objects in scope. To correct I scoped the grpc `objects` and then called  `grpc_shutdown()` once that scope was exited. This seems to have corrected the issue.

**New Grpc Client**

```
int main( )
{
    std::cout << "Press enter\n";
    std::cin.ignore( );

    std::cout << "Calling Grpc service\n";
    grpc_init( );

    { // <- Intentionally added scope here.

        grpc::SslCredentialsOptions options;

        if ( auto certificate{ ReadCertificate( ) } )
            options.pem_root_certs = std::move( certificate ).value( );
        else return 1;

        auto credentials{ grpc::SslCredentials( options ) };
        auto channel{ grpc::CreateChannel( "localhost:5001", credentials ) };
        auto stub{ MeterReadingService::NewStub( channel ) };

        std::cout << "Sending single packet\n";
        SendPacket( stub.get( ), 8000 );

        std::cout << "Sending multiple packets\n";
        StreamDiagnostics( stub.get( ), 3 );
    }

    std::cout << "Shutting down library\n";
    grpc_shutdown_blocking( );
    std::cout << "Shut down complete press enter to exit\n";
    std::cin.ignore( );
}
```